# How can you reformat all nested ObjectId's to string values?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am attempting to load MongoDB records into a SQL database where each object is just the Mongo data dump. I have 2-3 levels of nesting - I am wondering what the best way to get all ObjectID's reformatted to strings (or just not capturing any _id since they all have a UUID counterpart).

I have attempted to transform each object to a string, back to a dict, but that did not work. The error thrown is that "JSON object is not serializable"
I have tried $toString but that did not take care of the nested lists.

The Mongo doc is something like:

```
{ 
_id: ObjectId('xxxxxx'), 
name: 'steve',     
data: {     
    _id: ObjectId('xxxxxx'),
    value: xx,     
    } 
}
```

There can be another level of nesting too. I want it to become:

```
{ 
_id: 'xxxxxx',  
name: 'steve',     
data: {     
    _id: 'xxxxxx',     
    value: xx,     
    } 
}
```

The size of the documents, recursion would take too long. When loading as a JSON column in BigQuery, I get the error 'ObjectID is not JSON serializable' so it fails to upload.

Comment: Would you show an example MongoDB document and the acceptable format you want after transformation?

Comment: What format are the records in when you load to the SQL database?

Comment: Hi @rickhg12hs and Joe - I have edited my post to include the clarificaiton. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JSON module offers a default value if a type is not serializable, which was able to convert every `ObjectID` to str and be ready for upload to BQ.

```
json.dumps(data, default=str)
```